# Commerce 3 - Register user and save payment source after order complete for guest checkout

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, users, plugin-craftcommerce3, payment-methods, payment

We register and send account activation emails to guest customers after checkout using `registerUserOnOrderComplete`. We also want the guest customer to be able to save their payment card during checkout using `savePaymentSource` set to `true`.

Unfortunately, it seems `savePaymentSource` only works if a customer already has a user account and is logged in, prior to completing checkout.

We have reported to Craft as it feels like it should be handled natively, and it has been marked as a potential enhancement: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/2825

In the meantime, we are trying to come up with a workaround - possible options:

**a) TWIG/NATIVE: Registration (or login) form during checkout**

Create a registration (or login) form during checkout, and auto-login the user after registration, prior to completing checkout. This is the simplest to implement but has a couple of drawbacks; one, we'd need to disable email verification to auto-login (I think?). Two, it negatively impacts conversion. Three, accounts are created before checkout completion so, if people do not complete, we accrue 'dead' user accounts.

**b) MODULE: Register then login during checkout**

Custom module that registers a user using the checkout email, then auto-logins. This could either be an "invisible" step during checkout via a controller/action URL or run from an order/payment event (although we haven't found a suitable event that fires at the right time). We have to use a temporary password and send an email with a password reset link. Similar drawbacks to option A).

**c) MODULE: After checkout, register user and save order payment source to user**

Custom module that registers user after checkout, then retrieves order payment source and saves it to user, using something like [Craft's `createPaymentSource` method](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/9311f824ed24e303dfec46ab01b9b90823237410/src/controllers/PaymentsController.php#L252). This is favourable as it mimics what we hope will be native to Craft one day. However, when we use `createPaymentSource`, we get an error of `This PaymentMethod was previously used without being attached to a Customer or was detached from a Customer, and may not be used again.`

--

Does anyone have any better approach for this? Or any guidance for `createPaymentSource` in option C?